# get certain text string from outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get the text from an email body after the word "Company Name:" in my email. and put it into an excel spread sheet.

So for instance if we had Company Name: John's Building Services

Then we would get the text after Company Name: so our result would be 'John's Building Services'

I am using the following code:

```
Dim b4 As String
                        b4 = olkMsg.Body
                        Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
                        indexOfNameb = InStr(1, b4, "Company Name: ")
                        Dim finalString4b As String
                        finalStringb = Right(b4, Len(b4) - indexOfNameb - 13)
                        excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 1) = finalStringb
```

This gets the text after Company name, however in my email body I also have text on the lines below like:

```
Company Name: John's Building Services
Company number: 123
Company Status: live
etc
etc
```

the problem im getting is my code returns everything after company name: including all the text on the lines below and I only want to get the text directly after company name: which should be John's Building Services.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you're getting string from start index of Company name to the end as `Right()` is working - it takes specific number of chars starting from end of string.
What you want is to find start index of Company number (or any termination char you have there - vbCrLf maybe?) and use `Mid(br, start index, length)` where length is Len(b4)-start index of company number.

You should add this code:

```
Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
indexOfNamec = InStr(1, b4, "Company number: ")
```

and instead of

```
finalStringb = Right(b4, Len(b4) - indexOfNameb - 13)
```

use

```
finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfnameb)
```

I'm not sure about this `indexOfNamec - indexOfnameb` calculation if it defines proper length of finalString, but it should help.

Full test sub code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim b4 As String
        b4 = "blablablabla Company Name: CompName Company number: CompNumber blablablablabla"

    Dim indexOfNameb As Integer
        indexOfNameb = InStr(1, b4, "Company Name: ")

    Dim indexOfNamec As Integer
        indexOfNamec = InStr(1, b4, "Company number: ")

    Dim finalStringb As String

        finalStringb = Mid(b4, indexOfNameb, indexOfNamec - indexOfNameb)

        Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = finalStringb

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response howeve im really sorry but I am new to vba and don't quite understand what you mean, would it be possible to show me by demonstrating this for me?

Comment: thanks I get an invalid procedure error when I run that, it doesn't like the second line MID()

Comment: I edited my answer with full sub code which is working. Please double check your code and variable declarations.

Comment: @Rafel Wegner when I replace b4 = "blablablabla Company Name: CompName Company number: CompNumber blablablablabla" with b4 = olkmsg.body I get an invalid procedure error, do you know why this is?

Comment: @jamesdaley, according to MS this error may occure if length argument is negative (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201979). Check values of both indexes, maybe first is 0 (InStr is not finding string) or sth. Despite that you may find helpful this link: http://techniclee.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/ricky-custom-excel-export/ It shows some work with Outlook.